# SharePoint 2010 JSOM occasional permission issues (Error 405)

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-jsom

I'm having a strange behavior of SharePoint API using JSOM for SharePoint 2010.
When running a simple query like the following:

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
console.log(ctx.get_applicationName());
var web = ctx.get_web();
ctx.load(web);
ctx.executeQueryAsync(
    function() {
        alert("site title : " + web.get_title());
    },
    function(sender, args) {
        alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
);
```

Once it works fine and I receive the title. But most of the time I receive error 405 "Method Not Allowed" error. Also strange is applicationName always returns "Javascript Library".
Anyone outside there who had the same issues and maybe an idea of how to solve this?

Comment: What triggers the above JavaScript, or does it just run on page load? Are you using `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(yourcode,"sp.js");`?

Comment: Yes, I'm using ExecuteOrDelay...

Comment: Internet Explorer only has a `console` object when the F12 developer tools are open, so `console.log()` will cause your script to error in IE under ordinary circumstances. Does your code still run into problems when you remove `console.log(ctx.get_applicationName())` from your script?

Comment: 1. I'm not using IE, I'm using FF for debugging. 2. It happened already before using console and actually should make no difference either.